# Reverse engineer: How do I remove the black plastic that hides the ics?

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, reverse-engineering

I am hacking a circuit and it has this black plastic thing (see picture below) that hides part of the circuit.

[image]

How can I remove them to see what is inside?

What they are for? I think they are for chips that have no packaging, is this right?

What the real name of this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The real name is "glob top". As for how to remove it, I suspect that nasty chemicals are involved (strong HCl, maybe?) but have never done it.

Comment: Interesting blog post: http://uvicrec.blogspot.com/2013/04/heatgun-h2so4-decap.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [What kind of components are black blobs on a PCB?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9137/what-kind-of-components-are-black-blobs-on-a-pcb)

Comment: Here's [a very similar question to yours](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9137/what-kind-of-components-are-black-blobs-on-a-pcb). See [this answer in particular](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/16768/29792) as it mentions that one of the purposes of this blob is to protect the IC from reverse engineering.

Comment: And by your picture, it looks like you've already tried to scratch it out, haven't you?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is known as **Chip-On-Board** (COB) technology, the black material is **epoxy resin**, it is the same as the black material on ICs. Note than the bonding wires encased in the resin are very thin and fragile. COB technology is sometimes used to prevent reverse engineering.

This [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mT1FStxAVz4) demonstrates a process for removing the resin packaging on ICs using a hotplate, nitric acid, acetone, and a rotary tool.

This video [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQ5hXEK35WI) demonstrates a simpler (but more destructive) method for removing the resin from a COB, using just a heat-gun and a hobby knife. This method destroys the bonding wires.

And here's a related question, with more information about COBs: [What kind of components are black blobs on a PCB?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9137/what-kind-of-components-are-black-blobs-on-a-pcb)

Answer (score 0):

Red fuming nitric acid is supposedly the stuff to use. It's very nasty.