# Where is the memory inside this RFID tag

Tags: rfid

I dissected a RFID tag (Omni-ID). What I found is basically two components (wrapped in white plastic), a metal strip , and PCB having a wire:

I want to understand where is the memory to store stuffs? I was expecting a digital IC somewhere, but I could not find it any where.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The IC is likely underneath that plastic encapsulation. That black "blob" at the bottom right of your second picture.

The IC is probably much smaller than you are imagining. It's not going to be anything like an SOIC package that many picture a "digital IC" to be.

This method is used frequently in consumer electronics I've seen. TV remote controls coming to mind most quickly. You would need to peel back or scrape this layer to see the IC underneath.

[image: A Wikipedia picture of IC encapsulation.]

Comment: Ok. then I will try to look for that IC under the microscope,  and will post the picture.

Comment: Why do we put this black blob, and what this material called?

Comment: The black blob is just there to protect the chip and its connections. It is typically an [epoxy](http://www.icproto.com/capabilities-services/ic-assembly/encapsulation-options/). Here is a video of some being applied by hand. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ArqpRTUIEsc

Comment: Google "glob top" or "chip on board" or "ic encapsulation" for more info.

Comment: More info on glob tops and how to remove them... http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/108940/reverse-engineer-how-do-i-remove-the-black-plastic-that-hides-the-ics